# Putting a word in the select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to put the word "days" after the value, but the sql server is reacting that it cannot be converted. How can I also not select the negative integers difference.

```
SELECT PONo, PODeliveryDate,  DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate)  AS DayDiff 
FROM PurchaseOrder 
where POStatus='Complete' OR POStatus='Partially Completed' OR POStatus='Approved'   
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate ))
```

It gives me the difference of dates, but I cannot put the word days beside it.

I want it to look like 5 days not just 5

Comment: Try to convert the `DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate)` to `varchar` as `CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate) AS VARCHAR)+ ' days' as DayDiff`

Comment: This works perfectly :)

Comment: @CoderofCode use VARCHAR without specifying the length is really bad practice. In situations like parameters in procedures & functions, table creation and variable declarations, this will default to a length of 1. When casting as varchar without specifying the length, the length will default to 30. When debugging, you need a trained eye to tell which is which. So put length on.

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert the int value from `DATEDIFF()` to varchar and add your word

```
SELECT PONo
,      PODeliveryDate
,      CAST(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate) as varchar(10)) + ' days'  AS DayDiff 
FROM   PurchaseOrder 
WHERE  POStatus='Complete' 
   OR  POStatus='Partially Completed' 
   OR  POStatus='Approved'   
ORDER BY ABS( DATEDIFF( DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert this first `DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate)` into `VARCHAR` before you concatinate.

```
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate)) + 'days'
```

Answer (score 1):

In sqlserver 2012, you can use [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(CONCAT_TSQL);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLRESULTS.F1);k(SQL11.SWB.TSQLQUERY.F1);k(MISCELLANEOUSFILESPROJECT);k(DevLang-TSQL)&rd=true).

To only get the positive days, you can cast getdate as date and compare with that in the WHERE statement. Then you dont need to order by ABS datediff.

The WHERE clause is easier to read and maintain by using IN instead of OR, it also makes is easier to maintain.

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(DATEDIFF(DAY, GETDATE(), PODeliveryDate), ' days')  AS DayDiff 
FROM
  PurchaseOrder 
WHERE
  POStatus in ('Complete','Partially Completed','Approved')
  AND CAST(GETDATE() as date) <= PODeliveryDate
ORDER BY 
  PODeliveryDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like as follow:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10), GETDATE()) + ' Days'
```

You need to convert or cast into varchar before concate